# Groovy Operator Overloading Boxing of Java Primitives

Tags: java, groovy, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make use of Groovy's [Operator Overloading](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading), to use methods on my Java class in a Groovy context (a GroovyShell):

My class is, effectively, an ordered map of keys and values, so the interface looks something like this:

```
public interface GroovyMap<K, V> {
  // gets the value associated with the given key
  V getAt(K key);
  // gets the nth value, at the given index, in the ordered sequence of values
  V getAt(int index); 
}
```

The `getAt(K key)` method is working fine in Groovy:

```
GroovyMap<LocalDate, Double> map = ...
K key = ...
Double value = map[key];
```

However, the `getAt(int index)` method does *not* work in Groovy - i.e.:

```
GroovyMap<LocalDate, Double> map = ...
int i = 0;
Double value = map[i];
```

will throw a `CastClassException`:

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to javax.time.calendar.LocalDate

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here:

- Groovy has some funky behaviour with respect to numbers and primitives (e.g. `0.0` is effectively interpreted as `new BigDecimal("0.0")`), but I would have thought the explicitly defining `i` as an `int` would resolve that.
- It looks like the Groovy Operator Overloading is boxing any primitive values, and as such it's trying to pass `Double` to what is effectively the `getAt(LocalDate key)` method. However, I can't find any documentation to that effect. If that's the case, can you direct me to any such?
- Is there something else going on here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Which groovy version? Have you tried `@CompileStatic` for the calling code? For me (2.5.0-beta-2) this changes the behavior, but I for me the int works, whereas the Object fails with MissingPropertyException. Unless I add `@CompileStatic` which fixes it.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to have both methods called `getAt`?

Comment: Also, what's the use case for this Listy Map?  I worry you'll get the worst of both worlds... I can't recall needing a map that was also indexable... I guess you could be caching indexes to try and improve lookup speed?

Comment: @Mene - Groovy 2.4.7. The calling code is a very lightweight scripting environment - i.e. creating a GroovyScript, so I'm not sure that annotations would be suitable - i.e. the user could more easily just write `map.getAt(i)`.

Comment: @tim_yates - why both use getAt()? Because that's the Groovy operator overloading contract. What's the use case? It shouldn't matter, but this "listy map" is a time series, so it can be iterated on, or queried by index or key, and various other functionality that we think is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research, I found that there are other (method) operators that can be overloaded in Groovy - c.f. the [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html), and in particular, the `[call()][2]` operator. Note - the call operator can take any number of arguments.

I tried changing both `getAt()` methods to `call()`, but found that I was getting the same issue. However, if I kept *one* of the methods using `getAt()` (i.e. `getAt(int index)`) and changed *one* of the methods to use `call()` (i.e. `call(int index)`).

As such, I suspect that this issue is that Groovy treats the `int` as `Integer` ([Groovy uses Objects for everything](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_types)), it's then finds the `getAt(LocalDate date)` method, but can't cast an `Integer` to a `LocalDate`, and never identifies the `getAt(int index)` or tries to unbox the `Integer` to use it.